# Set JSTL condition from a JSP scriptlet, then pass to java script

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Ok.  I am not sure if this is really the goal of my question, but I am really trying to understand how to solve my problem.  I keep running into hurdles.  I am trying to pass a Boolean variable from a scriplet to JSTL, then call a js function to read whether its true or false.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> <!--Take out after testing --> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="test.html">
----
<% if (myJavaFunction.FormIsChanged() && myJavaFunction.ErrorCount()>0) {%>
<br />
<%@include file="/countallerrors.jsp"%>
<br />
<% } %>
<c:set var="ErrorPresent" value="false"/>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Basically my question is how can I set my "ErrorPresent" variable to be equal to `(myJavaFunction.FormIsChanged() && myJavaFunction.ErrorCount()>0)` ?

I am new to JSTL and after some research today, I found that its not in good practice to use scriptlets, so I would like to try and see if I can do this with JSTL.
Once I get the JSTL Boolean variable to function, I would like to pass to a java script function, and this function will determine if the form has errors before it is submitted.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Naina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is:

```
<c:set var="ErrorPresent" value="${(myJavaFunction.FormIsChanged() && myJavaFunction.ErrorCount()>0)}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that it's typically not great practice to use scriptlet--it's better to code up specific tags to encapsulate business logic. That helps enforce separation of presentation from control code.

But to accomplish what you want, try this:

```
<% boolean errorPresent = myJavaFunction.formIsChanged() && myJavaFunction.errorCount()>0; %>
```

The variable `errorPresent` is now available to your page's scope, and can be referenced using normal JSTL interpolation, like `<p>errorPresent: ${errorPresent}</p>`

On another stylistic note: Java style is for variable and method names to be `camelCased` with initial lowercase. Class names should be `MixedCase` with initial capital letter. My sample above corrects that. (Constants should be `ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES`)